# How do I add repeated text to a tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to be able to add text to a tkinter window in python, like a timer.
I want it to keep changing. I'm coding a tkinter program and I want it to display on a Tkinter window, not in the shell.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what was the issue you came across?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are multiple ways to do this, but this is the simplest and easiest solution

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label

window = Tk()
window.geometry("100x30")
count = 0

def timer():
    global count
    label1.config(text = str(count))
    count += 1
    label1.after(1000, timer) #this line calls the timer function after 1000 milliseconds.

label1 = Label(master = window, text = "1")  #use Labels to display text
label1.pack()
timer()

window.mainloop() #show the window
```

Comment: Ok, but this timer goes forward in time - infinitely. I want to know how to catch the users input for how long the timer is.